# How to switch to displayed UI and change font color in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I use Android Studio to write my App, the following code is my layout file, but sometimes Android Studio editor display A.png and sometime display B.png, it means that sometime the systme replace `android:text="@string/myabout"` with real string "About", but I don't konw how to switch to the UI.

And more, how can I change the code color of `android:text="@string/myabout"` and `android:text="Hard Code"`? You know that File-> Settings -> Editor is huge tree, I can't find what items I shoud to edit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myabout"
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hard Code"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**A.png**

[image]

**B.png**
[image]

Comment: Any more ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Color & Font** -> **XML** -> **Attribute Value**. Then you can set it *bold*, *italic*, *foreground*, *background* and something like that.

But why would you do that? Does it matter?

Comment: Thanks! I mean that I hope to change the color in Android studio editor. You know that File-> Settings -> Editor is huge tree in Android Studio, I can't find what items I shoud to edit.

Comment: Thank! but I can't find how to set the color of  attribute value when the text attribute value is Hard Code  in Settings -> Editor -> Color & Font -> XML -> Attribute Value